# Django Showing errror like "Import Error No module named redis"

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "queuearoo.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I am Accesing this from remote server using puTTY and getting the errors like the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 308, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/devbase/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/devbase/devbase/queuearoo/queuearoo/settings.py", line 2, in <module>
    import os,redis
ImportError: No module named redis
```

Comment: install it with "pip install redis"

Comment: Do you have redis installed on your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to install `redis` with this command:

```
pip install redis
```

also note that you are using virtual environment so you need to activate it first:

```
source /home/devbase/env/local/bin/activate
```

Comment: After the installtion of redis and djorm_pgtrgm it is still showing me error like this     from django.db import backend
ImportError: cannot import name backend

Comment: Yes, there is no backend name defined in `django/db/__init__.py` or `django/db/`. You want to import is `backends`. See https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends